# k8s HPA change inits new pods when reducing max to above current pod count?

Tags: kubernetes

Say I have 100 running pods with an HPA set to `min=100`, `max=150`. Then I change the HPA to `min=50`, `max=105` (e.g. max is still above current pod count). Should k8s immediately initialize new pods when I change the HPA? I wouldn't think it does, but I seem to have observed this today.

Comment: Why would it initialize new pods after reducing the min? It should only terminate pods.

Comment: If usage metrics for your existing pods don't justify having more than the min replicas count from your HPA: eventually, kubernetes would remove pods. Although that won't be "immediate".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as mentioned in the comments, in your specific case some pods will be terminated if usage metrics are below utilization target, no new pods will be created.

Second thing it's absolutely normal that is takes some time to scale down replicas - [it's because the
`stabilizationWindowSeconds` parameter is by default set to `300`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#default-behavior):

> ```yaml
> behavior:
> scaleDown:
>    stabilizationWindowSeconds: 300
>    policies:
>    - type: Percent
>      value: 100
>      periodSeconds: 15
> ```

So, if you have running HPA with configuration (min=100, max=150) for a long time, and you have changed to min=50, max=105, then after 300 seconds (5 minutes) your replicas will be scaled down to the 50 replicas.

Good explanation about how exactly `stabilizationWindowSeconds` works is in [this document](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/blob/master/keps/sig-autoscaling/853-configurable-hpa-scale-velocity/README.md#story-5-stabilization-before-scaling-down):

> ##### Story 5: Stabilization before scaling down
>
> This mode is used when the user expects a lot of flapping or does not want to scale down pods too early expecting some late load spikes.
>
> Create an HPA with the following behavior:
>
> ```yaml
> behavior:
>  scaleDown:
>    stabilizationWindowSeconds: 600
>    policies:
>    - type: Pods
>      value: 5
> ```
>
> i.e., the algorithm will:
>
> - gather recommendations for 600 seconds  *(default: 300 seconds)*
> - pick the largest one
> - scale down no more than 5 pods per minute
>
> Example for  `CurReplicas = 10`  and HPA controller cycle once per a minute:
>
> - First 9 minutes the algorithm will do nothing except gathering recommendations. Let's imagine that we have the following recommendations
>
> recommendations = [10, 9, 8, 9, 9, 8, 9, 8, 9]
>
> - On the 10th minute, we'll add one more recommendation (let it me  `8`):
>
> recommendations = [10, 9, 8, 9, 9, 8, 9, 8, 9, 8]
>
> Now the algorithm picks the largest one  `10`. Hence it will not change number of replicas
>
> - On the 11th minute, we'll add one more recommendation (let it be  `7`) and removes the first one to keep the same amount of recommendations:
>
> recommendations = [9, 8, 9, 9, 8, 9, 8, 9, 8, 7]
>
> The algorithm picks the largest value  `9`  and changes the number of replicas  `10 -> 9`

Another thing is that it depends which Kubernetes version, which `apiVersion` for the autoscaling are you using and which Kuberntes solution are you using. The behaviour could vary - check [this topic on GitHub](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/78761) with a bug reports.

If you want to have scale down done immediately (not recommended in the production), you can setup following:

```yaml
behavior:
    scaleDown:
      stabilizationWindowSeconds: 0
      policies:
      - type: Percent
        value: 100
        periodSeconds: 1
```

Also check:

- [Horizontal Pod Autoscaling](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) in particular [Example: change downscale stabilization window](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#example-change-downscale-stabilization-window) and [Example: limit scale down rate](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#example-limit-scale-down-rate)
- [Configurable scale up/down velocity for HPA](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/blob/master/keps/sig-autoscaling/853-configurable-hpa-scale-velocity/README.md#configurable-scale-updown-velocity-for-hpa)